# Total resistance from unit resistors

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, combinatorics, electrical-engineering

This problem is based on, [A337517](https://oeis.org/A337517), the most recent OEIS sequence with the keyword "nice".

> \$a(n)\$ is the number of distinct resistances that can be produced from a circuit with exactly \$n\$ unit resistors.

The sequence begins `1, 2, 4, 9, 23, 57, 151, 427, 1263, 3823, 11724, 36048, 110953, 342079`.

The goal of this challenge is to write a program that takes a positive integer `n` and outputs the possible resistances that can be formed with \$n\$ unit resistors, written as fractions (or floats, ordered pairs representing fractions, or in another essentially similar format) as in the following:

```
f(3) = [3/1, 3/2, 2/3, 1/3] 
     = [(3,1), (3,2), (2,3), (1,3)] 
     = [[3,1], [3,2], [2,3], [1,3]]
```

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so shortest code wins. Your program needs to be able to handle inputs up to \$n = 6\$ on [TIO](https://tio.run/#).

#### Examples

- With \$n = 1\$ resistor, the only possibility is a circuit with \$1 \Omega\$ total resistance.
- With \$n = 2\$ resistors, there are only \$a(2) = 2\$ possibilities:

  1. Resistors in sequence resulting in \$2 \Omega\$ total resistance.
  2. Resistors in parallel resulting in \$\frac 12 \Omega\$ total resistance.
- With \$n = 3\$ resistors, there are \$a(3) = 4\$ possibilities with resistances \$3 \Omega, \frac 32 \Omega, \frac 23 \Omega\$, and \$\frac 13 \Omega\$:

  1. [image: Resistors in series: 3 Ohms]
  2. [image: Resistors in series, then parallel: 3/2 Ohms]
  3. [image: Resistors in series within parallel: 2/3 Ohms]
  4. [image: Resistors in parallel: 1/3 Ohms]

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that not all circuits can be formed by recursively taking components in parallel or series. I think this means we can't necessarily obtain the resistances using \$n-1\$ applications of \$s(a,b)=a+b\$ and \$p(a,b)=ab/(a+b)\$.

Comment: I see the series/parallel circuit vs general circuit distinction is discussed on the [OEIS page](https://oeis.org/A337517), comparing to other OEIS sequences for limited circuits. The table shows that \$n=6\$ suffices to distinguishes circuits without only series and parallel subcomponents, which give only 53 of the 57 possible values. But adding bridges gives matching values until \$n=8\$, so answers testing only up to \$n=6\$ should be careful that they indeed compute the full set of resistances for all \$n\$.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg—thanks! I've removed that case to sidestep the details.

Comment: Wondering if there's a Mathematica builtin for this.

Comment: Not to be confused with [A180414](https://oeis.org/A180414) which, if I understand correctly, counts the number of distinct resistances with _up to \$n\$_ unit resistors.

Comment: @user—I've updated the prompt to allow the use of floats.

Comment: In order to be at least theoretically correct, one should implement generating arbitrary graph circuits and computing their total resistances by Kirchhoff's laws, as illustrated in [this pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20111123142636/http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~gottlieb/tr/2003-oct-3.pdf). (And it contains a full-page worth of Mathematica code.)

Comment: One could, of course, only include parallel and series circuits, and then add hardcode 4 extra numbers for the n = 6 case :)

Comment: @user Except that such an answer will be flagged as a non-answer :(

Comment: Maybe this question is too hard. But just because it’s [tag:code-golf] doesn’t mean that a 1000 byte answer is unimpressive!

Comment: @Bubbler I think it is easier than that. For unit resistors you can compute the [effective resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistance_distance) using only the graph laplacian and a pseudoinverse.

Comment: This challenge was nominated for, and won, the "Most Underappreciated Challenge" category of [Best of CGCC 2020](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20639/79857)! There's a +500 bounty as a reward (since this is a question, you can choose any of your answers for it to be awarded to). There's also a [Best of CGCC](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118629/best-of-2019-and-2020) chat room if you have any questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 734 bytes

```python
import fractions as F,itertools as I
r=range
s=set
P=lambda G,p=[0]:[x for a,b in G if(p[-1]==a)*(1-(b in p))for x in(P(G,p+[b])if b-1else[p+[b]])]
def R(G):
 G+=tuple((b,a)for a,b in G);B=s(b for a,b in G);n=1+max(B)
 if s(G)-s(x for p in P(G)for e in zip(p,p[1:])for x in[e,e[::-1]])or len(B)-n:return 0
 M=[[0]*(n+1)for _ in B];M[0][0],M[0][n],M[1][1]=[F.Fraction(1)]*3
 for a,b in G:M[a][a]+=a>1;M[a][b]-=a>1
 for i in r(n):
	for j in r(i,n):
	 if M[j][i]:break
	M[i],M[j]=M[j],M[i];M[i]=[x/M[i][i]for x in M[i]]
	for j in r(n):M[j]=[a-(j!=i)*b*M[j][i]for a,b in zip(M[j],M[i])]
 return 1/sum(M[a][n]-M[b][n]for a,b in G if a==0)
f=lambda n:s(map(R,I.combinations_with_replacement([(a,b)for a in r(n)for b in r(a,n+1)],n)))-s([0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVLBbtswDD3XX8EeglKJ3MYbsIMD7ZBDgh4MFL0KQiAncqvMlgVZwbL9fEY5SdsMIEQ9gnoiH@n/xPfefTudbOf7EKEJehtt7wbQA6y4jSbEvm9H@JwFEbR7M9kgBhOzF9Hqrt5pWHMv5FyV8ghNH0DzGqyDNdgGvcwLJYRmUyxyHOOesZR1pDu@IL2dyVox20CdF6YdjBwDiqlsZxp4xTUrM1jPRDz41iDWXLOvv7DFUgzEfBtzoph1@ohLllEZMBBLPuC5Pp9y6OeRxiTw13r03MuiVB@1ScONLEsqXzEKtcYRWe7KYOIhOJhnUAlJXU/RzYrx1SZRLdWioigZH71LvlBkQq4eVxd5sWBq@j27KbqspFZkM6F/FosR1CpP4JxnU1ZAR3LcJbw/Y8vHSOqyknslrSrrYPSv7K6iO08xkQ6e4CIdQh6fkie7NgsJqxteYh3fSp3j/l5YNq2nlw@@VJ2U@2CnkcFFnuJpOHQ4NuFUXlEn5P9bDtBCzFnWXNfIlQN22uMrf37c9l1tnR5XcfPbxvdNML7VW9MZF1Ei0Zy34FpsAvUZaJ4mokgXloZOU2CnTwHTAmPBf1AKyeaDdREeGpzsGAiYDA8wAdK0QcvY6R8)

I probably missed a bunch of golfing opportunities, but it's under 1000 bytes at least! I could have used SymPy for row reduction but went for a pure python answer instead.

Graphs are represented as lists of edges.

`P` generates all paths from vertex 0 to 1, used to determine if any resistors are unused (if they don't appear in any path).

`R` accepts a graph and returns the resistance between vertex 0 and 1, or `0` if the graph is invalid (it has unused edges/resistors or unused vertices). It does this by solving a system of linear equations of the voltages at each vertex.

`f` enumerates all graphs and generates the distinct resistances as a `set`. `0` from invalid graphs is removed.

Here are the results for 1 to 6 (as output by the footer in TIO):

```python
f(1) = set([Fraction(1, 1)])
f(2) = set([Fraction(1, 2), Fraction(2, 1)])
f(3) = set([Fraction(3, 2), Fraction(3, 1), Fraction(1, 3), Fraction(2, 3)])
f(4) = set([Fraction(1, 4), Fraction(3, 4), Fraction(4, 1), Fraction(5, 2), Fraction(1, 1), Fraction(4, 3), Fraction(2, 5), Fraction(3, 5), Fraction(5, 3)])
f(5) = set([Fraction(3, 8), Fraction(7, 4), Fraction(4, 7), Fraction(5, 1), Fraction(5, 8), Fraction(7, 3), Fraction(5, 6), Fraction(2, 1), Fraction(3, 7), Fraction(8, 5), Fraction(1, 2), Fraction(6, 7), Fraction(7, 6), Fraction(1, 5), Fraction(1, 1), Fraction(5, 4), Fraction(4, 5), Fraction(7, 5), Fraction(6, 5), Fraction(7, 2), Fraction(2, 7), Fraction(8, 3), Fraction(5, 7)])
f(6) = set([Fraction(1, 2), Fraction(5, 9), Fraction(2, 1), Fraction(1, 3), Fraction(8, 13), Fraction(6, 1), Fraction(1, 1), Fraction(7, 12), Fraction(3, 11), Fraction(13, 5), Fraction(12, 5), Fraction(3, 1), Fraction(1, 6), Fraction(7, 11), Fraction(10, 3), Fraction(3, 4), Fraction(11, 13), Fraction(11, 10), Fraction(4, 9), Fraction(2, 9), Fraction(11, 5), Fraction(10, 7), Fraction(3, 10), Fraction(5, 6), Fraction(3, 2), Fraction(13, 7), Fraction(13, 11), Fraction(7, 10), Fraction(7, 9), Fraction(13, 8), Fraction(10, 9), Fraction(5, 4), Fraction(11, 8), Fraction(5, 11), Fraction(4, 5), Fraction(8, 11), Fraction(6, 11), Fraction(5, 13), Fraction(9, 10), Fraction(2, 3), Fraction(11, 4), Fraction(6, 5), Fraction(9, 4), Fraction(11, 7), Fraction(7, 13), Fraction(13, 6), Fraction(11, 3), Fraction(4, 3), Fraction(6, 13), Fraction(12, 7), Fraction(9, 5), Fraction(10, 11), Fraction(9, 7), Fraction(9, 2), Fraction(5, 12), Fraction(11, 6), Fraction(4, 11)])
```